# What should my IPN listener do if it fails my conditions?

Tags: php, paypal, listener, paypal-ipn

I am working on putting conditions into my Paypal IPN listener such as making sure the transaction number does not match a previous number in my database, making sure the receiver email is correct, etc. What am I supposed to do if one of these tests fail? Does it stop the payment? Should the user be redirected somewhere? All help is appreciated!

Comment: I just checked our code. If something is wrong it logs an error and doesn't update the user's account. It doesn't send anything back to PayPal, whether successful or not. I think by the time the listener runs, the customer's account has already been debited.

Comment: But this is old code that I had little to do with, I can't guarantee that it's actually the correct procedure.

Comment: sounds more like business practice rather than coding logic

Comment: @nogad Good point. Is there a good forum I could post this in?

Comment: @Barmar Where does the logged info go?

Comment: It writes into files on our server, so we have a record of all the successful and failed transactions. We then have cron jobs that create reports based on them. These are our own custom files, nothing to do with PayPal.

Comment: Your code for PayPal IPN listener is called by PayPal website when the payment is done by user and when the user is still on PayPal website. So you can not redirect the user to anywhere. Also, what you want to do, all should be done in the `"VERIFIED"` section of your code, so you also do not return any data to PayPal. You should handle what you want to do on your side, then as @Barmar said, log your data into local file or databse and then monitor these log files manually or by some type of custom log viewer you write for your application...

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Of course you have set two links in PayPal for success and cancel which PayPal will return users to one of these links depending on the status of the payment. Let say one of your conditions fails, but the payment was successful on PayPal. You can set a record in your databse for that condition + the `userID` or any unique key you have from the user who has done the payment. Then in your success page, you can check query that table with the `userID` of the user visiting that page and if any records found, it means something went wrong. Then you can do what ever you have to do in the situation

Comment: But you have to be careful using this method, because user may close the browser and does not return to your website after the payment!

Comment: @EhsanT If you want to combine your comments and post as an answer, I can mark as solved

Comment: If it really helped you solve your problem or at least had put you on the right track sure. But the reason I used comment instead of answer was that I thought it's not a real answer(cause there is not really a real answer to your question) and it's only my opinion/way on using IPN :)

Comment: @EhsanT Between you and Barmar I have a better understanding of how I can move forward.

Comment: Great, I'll try to combine my comments and write an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combining my comments into one single answer here just in case it may help you and any other future visitor who may have same question :)

Your code for PayPal IPN listener is called by PayPal website when the payment is done by user and when the user is still on PayPal website.

So you can not redirect the user to anywhere. Also, what you want to do, all should be done in the "VERIFIED" section of your code, so you also do not return any data to PayPal.

You should handle what you want to do on your side, then as @Barmar said, log your data into local file or database and then monitor these log files manually or by some type of custom log viewer you write for your application...

Of course you have set two links in PayPal for success and cancel which PayPal will return users to one of these links depending on the status of the payment.

When sending a user from your site to PayPal for payment, you can send some custom data in a field named `custom` you can send `userID` or any unique id of current user with this field. and then when PayPal calls your IPN listener, will send this field along with transaction data to you.

Let say one of your conditions fails, but the payment was successful on PayPal. You can set a record in your database or local file for that condition + the `userID` or unique key you have from the user who has done the payment(from the custom field). Then in your success page, you can query that table with the `userID` of the user visiting that page and if any records found, it means something went wrong. Then you can do what ever you have to do in the situation(Show related messages or etc.)

But you have to be careful using this method, because user may close the browser and does not return to your website after the payment!

So you can have your code in the success link, but you have to monitor the transaction records on your administration part as well. Because you may need to contact the user on failing some of your conditions or any other situation which needs the human interaction from your side...